# Calculating the value of $\cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \arccos \frac{3}{5}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help finding the value of $$\cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \arccos \frac{3}{5}\right)$$

My try:
let $\theta = \frac{1}{2} \arccos \frac{3}{5}$, then $2\theta = \arccos \frac{3}{5}$ and $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$
Now let $A = 2\theta$, and $A \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ So $\cos A = \frac{3}{5} $ and $\sin A = \frac{4}{5} $. I noticed that I got stuck and wasn't getting closer to the answer.

Can someone please give me a **HINT AND NOT THE ANSWER**? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $ \cos(x) = 2\cos^2 \left ( \frac x 2 \right ) - 1 $

Comment: Are you familiar with the *half-angle identity* for cosine?  $$\cos \Bigl( \frac{1}{2} t \Bigr) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos t}{t}}.$$

Comment: @SammyBlack I think your $\;t\;$ in the root's denominator must be a $\;2\;$ .

Comment: Oops.  Typing too fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint with a trigonometric identity:

$$\cos x=2\cos^2\frac x2-1$$

Comment: Should I let $\theta = \arccos \frac{3}{5}$?

Comment: @AspiringMathlete Sure, *that* is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since:
$$\cos\frac{x}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}$$
it follows that:
$$\cos\left(2\arccos\frac{3}{5}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{3}{5}}{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.$$